# Why does SQL Server's GUI mangle my views?

Tags: sql-server

When I create a view in SQL Server 2005 and someone later opens it in the GUI modify mode it sometimes completely rearranges my joins.  Often to the point it's virtually no longer readable.  If I look at it in the GUI it's changed as well from what I originally wrote.  Sometimes the join lines no longer even point to a field and the join symbol has "fx".  I assume it has "optimized" it for me.  Is there a way to prevent this from happening?  And what does "fx" mean?

Originally it was something like this:

FROM         dbo.Stop 
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN  dbo.StopType ON dbo.Stop.StopTypeID = dbo.StopType.StopTypeID
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN  dbo.CityState ON dbo.Stop.City = dbo.CityState.City AND dbo.Stop.State = dbo.CityState.State
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN  dbo.vwDrivers ON dbo.Stop.DriverID = dbo.vwDrivers.DriverID
             LEFT OUTER JOIN  dbo.truck ON dbo.Truck.TruckID = dbo.Stop.TruckID
                     INNER JOIN    dbo.vwTicketIDFirstStopLastStop  ON dbo.vwTicketIDFirstStopLastStop.TicketID = dbo.stop.ticketid
                     LEFT  OUTER JOIN      dbo.Company ON dbo.Company.CompanyID = dbo.vwTicketIDFirstStopLastStop.BillToCompanyID

Now it's this.

FROM         dbo.Truck RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.Stop INNER JOIN
                      dbo.StopType ON dbo.Stop.StopTypeID = dbo.StopType.StopTypeID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.CityState ON dbo.Stop.City = dbo.CityState.City AND dbo.Stop.State = dbo.CityState.State LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.vwDrivers ON dbo.Stop.DriverID = dbo.vwDrivers.DriverID ON dbo.Truck.TruckID = dbo.Stop.TruckID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.vwTicketIDFirstStopLastStop LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.Company ON dbo.Company.CompanyID = dbo.vwTicketIDFirstStopLastStop.BillToCompanyID ON dbo.vwTicketIDFirstStopLastStop.TicketID = dbostop.ticketid

Comment: can you give us an example of the initial and rearranged views?

Comment: I added an example to the original question, thanks.

Comment: I hate that that it does that. The query designer is good for starting with to avoid typing, though. Frick'n Frontpage used to do the same thing with HTML -  I *HATED* that even more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot. That's why you should never, ever use it.

"Fx" means that the join is not a simple column-to-column link, but involves a function (that's also why it can't point to a field, of course). It should NOT do that by itself, though,

Comment: If only there was a way to train my co-workers to stop doing that.

Answer (score 1):

I hate the view GUI

I use RightClick->ScriptViewAs->Alter To->New Query Editor Window

So much nicer :)

Answer (score 0):

It's the result of the view GUI parsing the SQL into it's own internal DOM style format and then writing it back out - much in the same way that HTML editors take in XHTML and emit stuff differently to how you wanted it :(